# from pdf to shiny and from shiny to pdf

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, r-markdown

I want to create a shiny app for a fillable DnD character sheet.
The character sheet exists rn as an interactive pdf but it's not very useful nor has all options.
How is it possible to recreate the "same" pdf using rmarkdown?
I am developing the shiny part but I don't know how to make the pdf part.
The [pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7bgtLBs7XYlaGM2X2dFdEQ1NE0/view) I want to recreate.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Have you looked at [tutorials](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/articles_intro.html), resources and examples of creating a R Markdown document? Did you want to make an [interactive R Markdown document](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html%2F#overview) that leverages shiny? Or maybe a shiny app that renders a [downloadable report](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html) (R Markdown pdf)? I would look further into what you need and perhaps try a brief demo. Right now it appears you may not have a specific coding question yet.

Comment: I have some example for the shiny code that I can post here, although I don't think is very useful as my question is about a different thing.
From the pdf I posted, I will recreate a shiny app so a user will select various options and on the background, the app will make simple calculations to produce the statistics for the character sheet. My issue is that I want in the end to have almost the same pdf produced from the shiny app with all the selections the user has made.
So it is downloadable report but I can't find how to create the pdf as is on the markdown.

Comment: @Ben Maybe [flexdashboard](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/index.html) could be used to produce the report?

Comment: @K Geles - did you look at this link I mentioned in the previous comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html? This shows an example of creating a downloadable report (including in pdf format) from a shiny app. The app can pass relevant info into the report through parameters when it is rendered. It sounds like this might be closest to what you want to do.

Comment: @Ben yes I checked but the problem is how to make the formating of this pdf

Comment: @k Geles - could you describe more about formatting desired? R Markdown with pdf rendering can include tables, multiple columns, LaTeX, etc. But I'm wondering if you are trying to closely match the pdf you shared in your question, that does sound like quite a task.

Comment: @ Ben exactly, that is what I'm looking for,  match with that pdf

Comment: @K Geles - my apologies, this is beyond me. I know you could build .Rmd files with tables that would "work" from shiny data, but it would be challenging to recreate the exact same layout as your pdf with the specific images, different formatting, columns, etc. You can import a pdf as an image, but unaware of adding text to it (like a fillable pdf). Perhaps you could consider another question posted about working with your pdf file in R Markdown specifically (and take Shiny out of the title)? I wish I could be of more help.

Comment: @Ben thank you, I will probably make another question!